# XAML Disabling Events on Child Elements when moving Parent

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, winrt-xaml

I have an ItemsControl that Contains a few buttons, My Items control is movable, you can move it around by dragging it. the issue is when I click and drag my control to move it, and leave the mouse on top of a button inside the control, it fires the click event of the button which I dont' want/

So While I am moving the control around I want to disable any events on the child buttons, I used IsDisabled = true but that changes the appearance of the buttons too which I dont want.

Comment: inside button click event handler you can check with any property if drag operation in progress. If so, just return from the handler with e.handled=true;

Answer (score 0):

you can set  IsHitTestVisible property of button to false

`IsHitTestVisible="False"`